# Is it possible to save mocha reporter as well as displaying it?

Tags: mocha.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer and mocha for some tests. By default, the reporter displays results at the end of a run in the console.

It is also possible to save the report in a separate file.

I cannot seem to figure out how to both display the report **AND** save it? That way I can see the results in the console, but also have them saved for further usage.

I am using the following : `--reporter json --reporter-option output=./results/jsonreport.json`

If I remove the output, then I get it to display in my console.

Answer (score 0):

I use [nyc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc). Then, in `package.json`:

```json
        ...,
        "scripts": {
            ...
            "test": "nyc --reporter=lcov mocha --recursive --exit *test-dir-name-goes-here*",
            ...
        },
        ...
```

It outputs the test results in real-time to stdout, and then stores them in the `coverage` directory (default).

Comment: Thank you - I'll look into it. I use xfvb to run the tests, I'll have to see if they're compatible.